# .on event keeps getting fired over and over again

Tags: javascript, onclick, jquery

I'm trying to setup an event where it fires after my element is opened. So I have a tooltip and I have a click event which shows the tooltip. Then when that happens I setup a document click event that gets fired so if the user clicks anywhere on the stage it removes all tooltips. But what's happening is it gets called before the tooltip even gets a chance to show. So it's firing the document event over and over again.

```
 $('.container img').popover({placement:'top', trigger:'manual', animation:true})
    .click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        el = $(this);

        if(el.hasClass('active')){
            el.popover('hide');

        }else{
            clearDocumentEvent();
            el.popover('show');

                $(document).on('click.tooltip touchstart.tooltip', ':not(.container img)', function(){
                    hideAllTooltips();

                });

        }

        el.toggleClass('active');
    })

    var hideAllTooltips = function(){
        $('.container img').popover('hide');
        $('.container img').removeClass('active');
    }

    var clearDocumentEvent = function(){
        $(document).off('click.tooltip touchstart.tooltip');
    };
```

Comment: It does look somewhat weird to declare the functions as variables later in the script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from event bubbling.  You can verify this by doing the following test:

```
$(document).on('click.tooltip touchstart.tooltip', ':not(.container img)', function(){
    //hideAllTooltips();
    console.log($(this)); // will return .container, body, html
});
```

Try using [`event.stopPropogation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$(document).on('click.tooltip touchstart.tooltip', ':not(.container img)', function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     hideAllTooltips();
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/uPHk6/8/

---

Side note:
I recommend removing `.tooltip` from the `on` function like

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', ':not(.container img)', function(){
    e.stopPropagation();
    hideAllTooltips();
});
```